# group by consecutive period

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi，I have a column as below

```
+--------+--------+
| day    |  amount| 
+--------+---------
| 2      |   2    |
| 1      |   3    | 
| 1      |   4    | 
| 2      |   2    |
| 3      |   3    | 
| 4      |   3    |
| 5      |   6    |
| 6      |   6    |
+--------+--------+
```

now I want something like this sum day 1- day3 as row one , sum day2-day4 as row 2, and so on.

```
+--------+--------+
| day    |  amount| 
+--------+---------
| 1-3    |   14   |
| 2-4    |   10   | 
| 3-5    |   12   |
| 4-6    |   15   |
+--------+--------+
```

Could you offer any one help ,thanks!

Comment: Make a table of rows with values indicating the ranges. Do an inner join doe values between the two values.

Comment: hi,@shawnt00 could you be more specific. thanks ~

Comment: Try my Updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use a correlated subquery:

```
select day, day + 2 as end_day,
       (select sum(amount)
        from t t2
        where t2.day in (t.day, t.day + 1, t.day + 2)
       ) as amount
from (select distinct day from t) t;
```

This returns rows for all days, not limited to the last 4.  If you really want that limit, then you can use:

```
select day, day + 2 as end_day,
       (select sum(amount)
        from t t2
        where t2.day in (t.day, t.day + 1, t.day + 2)
       ) as amount
from (select distinct day
      from t
      order by day
      offset 1 limit 99999999
     ) t
order by day;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Way 1:**

Simply use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT '1 - 3' [Day], SUM(Amount)Amount FROM Your_Table WHERE Day BETWEEN 1 AND 3
UNION ALL
SELECT '2 - 4', SUM(Amount) FROM Your_Table WHERE Day BETWEEN 2 AND 4
UNION ALL
SELECT '3 - 5', SUM(Amount) FROM Your_Table WHERE Day BETWEEN 3 AND 5
UNION ALL
SELECT '4 - 6', SUM(Amount) FROM Your_Table WHERE Day BETWEEN 4 AND 6
```

**Way 2:**

You have to create a table with date range and `JOIN` the Table.

```
CREATE TABLE Tab1 (Day INT, Amount INT)
INSERT INTO Tab1 VALUES( 2 ,2 )   
 ,(1, 3)    
 ,(1, 4)    
 ,(2, 2)   
 ,(3, 3)    
 ,(4, 3)   
 ,(5, 6)   
 ,(6, 6)

CREATE TABLE Tab2 (DateRange VARCHAR(10), StartDate INT, EndDate INT)
INSERT INTO Tab2 VALUES ('1 - 3',1,3)
    ,('2 - 4',2,4)
    ,('3 - 5',3,5)
    ,('4 - 6',4,6)

SELECT T2.DateRange,SUM(T1.Amount) Amount
FROM Tab1 T1
JOIN Tab2 T2 ON T1.Day BETWEEN T2.StartDate AND T2.EndDate
GROUP BY T2.DateRange
```

**OutPut:**

```
Day     Amount
1 - 3   14
2 - 4   10
3 - 5   12
4 - 6   15
```

Comment: Is there more practical way of solving this problem if the day range is more than a year? it would be tedious to write union all function , thanks @DineshDB

Comment: What is the database ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use integer division in order to calculate 'days buckets' and group by each bucket:

```
SELECT (day - 1) DIV 3 AS bucket, SUM(amount) AS total
FROM mytable
GROUP BY (day - 1) DIV 3;
```

**Output:**

```
bucket  total
-------------
0       14
1       15
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/POLBL46316)

To get the bucket string you can use:

```
SELECT concat(3 * ((day - 1) DIV 3 + 1) - 2, ' - ',
              3 * ((day - 1) DIV 3 + 1)) AS bucket, 
       SUM(amount) AS total
FROM mytable
GROUP BY (day - 1) DIV 3
order by day;
```

**Output:**

```
bucket  total
--------------
1 - 3   14
4 - 6   15
```

Note: The query  works only for consecutive non-overlapping intervals.